# Which Perl encoding for which HTML character set?

Tags: html, perl, character-encoding

I am writing a Perl script that fetches various HTML documents from many different web sites and tries to extract data from them. I have a problem with decoding those documents.

I know how to read the `charset` from a meta tag if there is one, and how to read this information from the HTTP header if available.

The results can be:

- UTF-8
- ISO-8859-1
- Shift_JIS
- Windows-1252

and many more

With this knowledge I want to decode the document in my Perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use Encode;
use Encode::JP;

# Maybe also use other extensions for Encode

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get($url); #$url is the documents URL

if ( $response->is_success ) {

    my $charset = getcharset($response);
    # getcharset is a self-written subroutine that reads the charset
    # from a meta tag or from the HTTP header (not shown in this example)

    # Now I know the documents charset and want to find its encoding:

    my $encoding = 'utf-8'; # default

    if ($charset eq 'utf-8') {
        $encoding = 'utf-8'; # Here $encoding and $charset are equal

    }
    elsif ( $charset eq 'Shift_JIS' ) {
        $encoding = 'shiftjis'; #here $encoding and $charset are not equal
    }
    elsif ( $charset eq 'windows-1252' ) {
        # Here I have no idea what $encoding should be, since there is no
        # encoding in the documentation that contains the string "windows"

    }
    elsif ( $charset eq 'any other character set' ) {
        $encoding = ???
    }

    my $content = decode($encoding, $result->content);

    # Extract data from $content
}
```

But I fail to find the correct encodings for some charsets that exist out there in the wild.

Comment: You should `use warnings` in preference to `-w` on the shebang line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For HTML documents, all you need is

```
my $content = $response->decoded_content();
```

It will use both the value of the *charset* attribute in the HTTP header and the META element as needed.

> *But I fail to find the correct encodings for some charsets that exist out there in the wild.*

Encode doesn't [support](http://search.cpan.org/~dankogai/Encode-2.78/Encode.pm#Listing_available_encodings) all encodings that have ever existed, but I'm surprised you encountered an HTML page it couldn't decode. It could simply be a case of creating an alias, but you haven't provided any details for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

See [Encode::Supported](http://p3rl.org/Encode::Supported). Basically, most of the encodings should *just work*™.

```
binmode STDIN, ':encoding(Shift_JIS)';
binmode STDIN, ':encoding(windows-1252)';
```

Both work without errors.

Comment: What does that have to do with decoding HTTP responses?

Comment: Does this mean, that **every** charset-name that I will find in **any** html-document is also a valid encoding-name that I can use within the module `Encode`? If this is so, why is this important fact not mentioned in the documentation of this module?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: No, but most of them are.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast, Aside from being rather obvious that it can't support all encodings since there's no official list of encodings*, it is mentioned in the documentation. Specifically, it's mentioned on the third line and there's a whole section on the topic ("Listing available encodings"). // * This begs the question, what do you mean when you say you have a valid encoding name!?